# How do we sync firebase users into Big Query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

We have been using the firebase extension to stream (and import) our firestore collection data in BigQuery. That works great.

I was looking for a way to do the same for the users in Firebase Authentication. Any way we can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Firebase Extension to export users to BigQuery.

But there is an API in the Admin SDKs that allows you to [read all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), so if you combine that with the APIs to [write data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/bigquery-write-api-explained-overview-write-api) you can build the functionality yourself.